# How to Create An Auto Complete textbox using database values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to use the textbox `search_txt` to filter my `DataGridView` values, such that whatever letter entered in the textbox auto completes and I am getting an error

Here's the method created

```
void AutoCompleteText()
    {
        search_txt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        search_txt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = conDB;
        command.CommandText = "select CCSpn_CODE,CCLname,CCFname,CCMname,CCDOB,CCgender,CCSchool,CaClass,CCVillage,CCSiblings,CCGuardian,CCContact,CCcurrentDt,CCImage from abaanaCC";
        OleDbDataReader myreader;
        try
        {
            conDB.Open();
            myreader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (myreader.Read())
            {
               //Error Here!!!!! 
                string sName = myreader.GetString("CCLname")
                coll.Add(sName);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
        search_txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll;

    }
```

Here's code that loads the `DataGridView`

```
 private void btnloaddata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conDB.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conDB;
            command.CommandText = "select CCSpn_CODE ,CCLname ,CCFname ,CCMname,CCDOB,CCgender,CCSchool,CaClass,CCVillage,CCSiblings,CCGuardian ,CCContact,CCcurrentDt,CCImage from abaanaCC";
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
           // this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["CCLname"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to Load Data");
        }
        conDB.Close();

    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: The **Error** is **The best Overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid arguments**

Comment: There may be a chance that you are getting a null value and it fails when converting it to a string. Is there a way for you to check that?

Comment: got a solution that already

Comment: Then it might be handy to still post that solution, incase future users mght have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the solution for the **AutoCompleteMethod**

```
  void AutoCompleteTxtBox() 
    {
        txt_Search.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        txt_Search.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\ELIJAH\vs_Proj\Abaana\Abaana\abaana.mdb";
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select CCSpn_CODE ,CCLname ,CCFname ,CCMname,CCDOB,CCgender,CCSchool,CaClass,CCVillage,CCSiblings,CCGuardian ,CCContact,CCcurrentDt,CCImage from abaanaCC";
        //cmd.CommandText = "select * from abaanaCC";
        OleDbDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {//error was here
            string lname = myReader["CCLname"].ToString();
            coll.Add(lname);
       }
        txt_Search.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll;
        conn.Close();
    }
```